# InvalidOperationException during EF6 code-first database initialization (principal end of this association must be explicitly configured)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm using EF6 and code-first approach to implement custom properties for products belongs to certain categories (or any other classification tree: aspect). I'd like to implement the following database structure through components.

[image: desired database structure]

Direct link to the image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgsD0.png)

(The relation links moved to the corresponding primary/foreign key in the image)

When I added the AssignedOption navigational property to the Aspects class/table, I got the following exception during seeding:

"Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'storeBeacon.Models.Aspect' and 'storeBeacon.Models.AspectOption'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."

The code of the related classes are the following:

```vb
Public Class Aspect

    <Key>
    Public Property Id As Integer

    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property Type As String

    Public Property CardinalityMinimum As Byte

    Public Property CardinalityMaximum As Byte


    <ForeignKey("AssignedOptionId")>
    Public Overridable Property AssignedOption As AspectOption
    Public Property AssignedOptionId As Integer?

End Class

Public Class AspectOption


    <Key>
    Public Property Id As Integer

    <ForeignKey("AspectId")>
    Public Overridable Property Aspect As Aspect
    Public Property AspectId As Integer


    <ForeignKey("ParentId")>
    Public Overridable Property Parent As AspectOption
    Public Property ParentId As Integer?

    Public Property Label As String


End Class
```

So can you please tell me how to fix this problem without fluent API if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to set them up as a one-to-one relationship. In which case you'll need to pick one of them to be the primary table of the relationship, and the other to use a  FK into it. Because right now you can't use 2 FKs to point to each other, since it confuses Entity Framework.

EDIT: Based on the comment, I've figured out what you need to do. I wrote my code in C#, but I'm sure it's easily translatable to VB.

In `Aspect`:

```
public int AssignedOptionID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("AssignedOptionID"), InverseProperty("Aspects")]
public virtual AspectOption AssignedOption { get; set; }

public virtual List<AspectOption> AspectOptions { get; set; }
```

In `AspectOption`:

```
[ForeignKey("AspectID"), InverseProperty("AspectOptions")]
public virtual Aspect Aspect { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ParentID")]
public virtual AspectOption Parent { get; set; }

public virtual List<Aspect> Aspects { get; set; }
```

In your DbContext's `OnModelCreating` method (yes, you have to do *something* in Fluent API, since otherwise it will throw an exception saying that there are multiple cascade paths):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Aspect>()
            .HasMany(a => a.AspectOptions)
            .WithRequired(a => a.Aspect)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Thank you, but not really. They are two different connection with different functionality. If you see the diagram (the desired db), you won't see one connection with two keys in the ends. So all options (aspectoption) belongs to one aspect (criteria, filter, whatever). Like country (aspect) and US (option). The other connection something else like an aspect (like 'wifi standard type') could be assigned to an option ('wifi router' option of the 'device type' aspect). So they are different connections, and definitely not 1-1.

Comment: So they are essentially one-to-many with each other? An Aspect can have many Options, and an Option can have many Aspects.

Comment: Every option belongs to an aspect, that's a mandatory one-to-many relationship. Every aspect could be assigned to one option, which makes this connection an optional one-to-many connection as you can assign more aspects to one options. But my point is that not the cardinality is the issue here, the function of the relationships are completely different. This logic/structure could be easily designed by SQL (the picture I attached), but confuses EF database generator for some reason, because it somehow wants to handle this as one DB relation.

Comment: That's a working solution. I don't even need the fluent API as I switched off the cascade deleting for the entire db. Thank you.